# Passing Credit Card Data To Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, credit-card

In my project, I need to take down a customers credit card number, for a future payment, and store it.

How can I ensure the security of the data being entered on my MVC View when being passed to the Controller Action that is going to store the data?

I am aware of SSL as a base requirement, but is there a method specifically that I should use?

Please note, I am unable to use any third party processors, or any other method. I have secure methods of card storage, as we are transitioning from a Desktop Application, however I am concerned with security between Data Entry and the Controller Action.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => newPayment.cardnumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(p => newPayment.cardnumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => newPayment.cardnumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Note that, independent of the technology used, and depending on external business/legal factors, you may also want to check PCI compliance, especially if your retaining the card numbers in a persistent store of some sort.

Comment: I would avoid storing credit card data unless you *really* need to.

Comment: It's a broad and complex topic but just as a side note SSL encrypts data during transit, it doesn't help you to securely store data in a database. Have a look at [Troy Hunt's blog](http://troyhunt.com) if you haven't already.

Comment: if you store vital information of that nature I would also recommend some sort of scrambling algorithm or encryption on those stored values.. nobody nobody would want their information compromised if you are storing in plain text

Comment: **PayPal** and **Authorize.Net** let you store customer's credit card information secure. If you want to recharge the card, just use the ID (or token). Think of two words - **HomeDepot** and **Target**.

Comment: Please review my edits, we are transitioning from a Desktop Application to a web based front-end, we have existing PCI Compliant Infrastructure.

Comment: If anyone has a method of passing secure data from View to Controller, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Stripe payments.
Stripe stores all the sensitive data for you and just hands you a token for access.